# Select urn at random and draw until first success

Tags: probability

You have $n$ urns, each containing $p_i$ white balls and $q_i$ black ones. One of the urns is selected uniformly at random, and balls are extracted with replacement from it until a black ball is found.

What is the distribution of the number of draws needed?

This is simply a random selection out of $n$ independent geometric distributions, but I'm unable to find this particular ensemble anywhere. Does this distribution have a proper name? Is it a geometric distribution itself?

Comment: No, but it's the average of geometric distributions.

Comment: @AndréNicolas : "Never" is a strong term. If $p_i=p_j$ for all $i,j$ and $q_i = q_j$ for all $i,j$, then you get a geometric distribution.

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman: Yes, the case where there is effectively one urn gives a geometric.

Comment: I've been doing some digging, and it seems that these things are called "mixtures", in this case, of a uniform distribution with a number of geometrics (or simply a number of geometrics, I'm not clear on the notation). The thing still is that although I know how to calculate the PDF of such a mixture, I'm looking for the theoretical properties of such a mixture itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is a finite mixture of geometric distributions. The  discrete uniform   $ 1/n$ is called the mixing distribution. Its distribution can be written as
$$p(x)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \text{Geom}(x|\frac{q_i}{p_i+q_i}),\; x=1,2\dots$$